# How to escape array iteration when exporting to .csv and fill columns with the iteration result only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, csv, export-to-csv

Apologies if there's a better way for asking this.

I'm trying to export `User` data to a `.csv` file but I'm having problems iterating through arrays. I'm getting the contents of the whole array in one column and nothing in the following columns. Example:

Suppose I have the headers `Company` and `Country`:

```
<% headers = [
  ... # some other headers
  "Company",
  "Country"
  ] %>

<%= CSV.generate_line(headers, row_sep:"", col_sep: ",") %>
```

Then I have an array of strings with the user values for `Company` name and `Country`, and I have to fill the corresponding column in the file with the correct value.

```
<% @user_preferences = ["Microsoft", "USA"] %>
```

I'm doing something like

```
<%= CSV.generate_line([
  ... # some other fields
  @user_preferences.each do |value|
    value
  end
], row_sep:"", col_sep: ",").html_safe %>
```

But instead of getting each `value` in a different column, I get `["Microsoft", "USA"]` in first column (`Company`) and nothing in the `Country` column.

What I understand is happening is it's filling the first column with whatever `@user_preferences` returns before going into the iteration block instead of assigning each `value` to a separate column.

I've tried with a hash instead of an array, but get the same results when iterating through it's keys/values (I get both values in the same column).

Is there a way to *escape* the iteration and fill each column with the correct value?

Comment: _"I'm trying to export User data to a .csv file"_ – but your code looks like you're trying to write the CSV output to a HTML template.

Comment: Yes, the .csv is just like any other html.erb view. But instead of rendering it, a download prompt is given.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to splice the contents of an array into another array literal. You can use the splat operator for this:

```
<%= CSV.generate_line([:some, :other, :fields, *@user_preferences],
                      row_sep:"", col_sep: ",").html_safe %>
```

It is equivalent to this:

```
[:some, :other, :fields, *["Microsoft", "USA"]]
```

Which gives:

```
[:some, :other, :fields, "Microsoft", "USA"]
```

Comment: The first `CSV.generate_line` creates the first line of headers. The second one generates each line containing the `User` data under each header.

The problem I'm having when iterating through the array is that instead of having each value of the array under the corresponding header, I get all the values under the first header and nothing in the following ones.

Comment: @pinkfloyd90 did you try the suggested fix?

Comment: @Stefan I opted for building the row contents array outside the `CSV.generate_line` and then passing the whole array to it.

Comment: @pinkfloyd90 the problem was that you added the `@user_preferences` array to the row-array instead of adding its elements. (which is what the splat operator `*` achieves) Hope you got it sorted out.